# Material-UI: Trigger transition when scroll to element

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend

I use react with Material-UI for my website and I would like to add some transitions. I've used a button so far to make a component appear, but I want it to appear when I scroll to the component then the transition trigger. I am using `<Grow/>` component from Material-UI, can you help me with that?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can listen to the `scroll` event in the container element and detect whether the elements inside it is in the viewport like below:

```js
function Scroller({ className, children, trackIds, onScrollToElement }) {
  return (
    <div
      className={className}
      onScroll={(e) => {
        for (let i = 0; i <= trackIds.length - 1; i++) {
          const id = trackIds[i];
          const trackedEl = document.getElementById(id);
          const scrollerEl = e.currentTarget;

          if (
            scrollerEl.scrollTop >
            trackedEl.offsetTop + trackedEl.offsetHeight - scrollerEl.offsetHeight
          ) {
            onScrollToElement(trackedEl);
          }
        }
      }}
    >
      {children}
    </div>
  );
}
```

### Explanation

- `scrollerEl` is the scrollable container element. Make sure to set the `overflow` CSS property of this element to `auto` to show the scrollbar when there is not enough space.
- `trackedEl` is the child element inside the scrollable container to keep track of, when the user scrolls to the `trackedEl`, the callback `onScrollToElement` is invoked.
- `scrollerEl.scrollTop`: number of pixels scrolled vertically. This is the scroll 'progress'. Before you scroll, the value is `0`, as you are scrolling down the value is increase by the pixels you've scrolled.
- `trackedEl.offsetTop + trackedEl.offsetHeight - scrollerEl.offsetHeight`: The number of pixels you have to scroll down to see the `trackedEl`

  - `trackedEl.offsetTop`: The distance in pixel of the `scrollerEl` top position to the `trackedEl` top position.
  - `trackedEl.offsetHeight`: The height of `trackedEl` including padding and border. This means you have to fully see the `trackedEl` before `onScrollToElement` fires
  - `scrollerEl.offsetHeight`: The height of `scrollerEl`. Subtracting this because before you start scrolling, you've already seen the top part of the container.

### Usage

```js
const classes = useStyles();
const [showButton, setShowButton] = useState(false);

return (
  <Scroller
    className={classes.container}
    trackIds={["myButton"]}
    onScrollToElement={(el) => {
      if (el.id === "myButton" && !showButton) {
        setShowButton(true);
      }
    }}
  >
    <div className={classes.topContent}>
      <Typography variant="h4">Top content</Typography>
    </div>
    <div className={classes.buttonContent}>
      <Grow in={showButton}>
        <Button id="myButton" variant="contained" color="primary">
          Primary
        </Button>
      </Grow>
    </div>
  </Scroller>
);
```

Props:

- `trackIds`: List of ids of the elements to keep track of in the `Scroller`. If we track every elements inside `Scroller`, it will affect the performance in complex UI.
- `onScrollToElement`: A callback that is executed when a tracked element is scrolled into view.

### Live Demo

[image: Edit 67105187/material-ui-transition-when-scroll]

Comment: Sorry but it doesn't work. onScrollToElement return always false and i don't know why

Comment: Do you mean `onScrollToElement` is never called? Did you pass the `trackIds` list and adding an id to the button? @ValiTalpas

Comment: Yes. Should I use `<Scroller />` in app.js? `    `

Comment: Did you set `Scroller` overflow style to `auto` like in my example? @ValiTalpas

Comment: Yes, I don't know what I'm doing wrong :(

Comment: Can you add your codesandbox here so I can troubleshoot it? @ValiTalpas

Comment: https://codepen.io/talpasvali/project/editor/AjYbzE

Comment: @ValiTalpas all 3 buttons are in the viewport at the start, `Scroller` only detects if the button is inside the viewport while scrolling, you can use [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/7557433/9449426) asnwer there to see if the button is in the viewport at the beginning and set its display accordingly. See [this](https://codesandbox.io/s/67105187material-ui-transition-when-scroll-forked-4xyp6?file=/demo.tsx) codesandbox.

Comment: In my visual studio code it's not at the beginning. It's ok, I appreciate your effort, I'll try to solve it somehow with your code